# Flutter Material Icons (for the web) don't work in release mode

Tags: flutter, release, flutter-web, google-material-icons

While trying out flutter-web for a website of mine, I found out that Material Icons are rendering in debug mode, but they are not working in release mode (getting replaced by boxes).
The code for `navBarMobile.dart` is here.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:eva_icons_flutter/eva_icons_flutter.dart';
import 'package:portfolio/globals/myColors.dart';
import 'package:portfolio/globals/myDimens.dart';
import 'package:portfolio/globals/mySpaces.dart';
import 'package:portfolio/globals/myString.dart';

class NavBarMobile extends StatefulWidget {
  _NavBarMobileState createState() => _NavBarMobileState();
}

class _NavBarMobileState extends State<NavBarMobile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: MyDimens.double_125,
      color: MyColors.white,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: MyDimens.double_20),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: MyDimens.double_16,
                      height: MyDimens.double_16,
                      color: MyColors.accentColor,
                    ),
                    MySpaces.hSmallestGapInBetween,
                    Text(
                      MyStrings.myName,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: MyColors.black,
                          fontFamily: 'poppins',
                          fontSize: MyDimens.double_20),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                MySpaces.vSmallestGapInBetween,
                Text(
                  MyStrings.myWork.toUpperCase(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                      letterSpacing: 0.5,
                      color: MyColors.black,
                      fontFamily: 'avenir-light',
                      fontSize: MyDimens.double_15),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Spacer(),
            Icon(Icons.menu, color: MyColors.accentColor, size: MyDimens.double_40,),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here are the screenshots of my from my laptop in

1. **Release mode** (using `flutter run --release`)

[image: Release mode browser screenshot]
2. **Debug mode** (using `flutter run`)

[image: Debug mode browser screenshot]

Additional Details:
**Browser** - Chrome
**OS** - Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Does your pubspec have `flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
` ?

Comment: Yes it does have that line.

Comment: I had a similar issue resolved after I commented out a conditional block using `kReleaseMod` and some Riverpod overrides. My belief at this point is that the images failed to render as result of improper data state during the widget build process.


I recommend trying a simple test app with a single icon and test a release version of it.  If that works then double check all those global dart files to make sure they're returning everything you're expecting.

Comment: Actually this issue had got resolved as per the article here. - https://ptyagicodecamp.github.io/how-to-fix-material-icons-for-flutter-web-hummingbird.html. Thanks to Randal Schwartz for helping me on Gitter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I have found a way out, I'd like to share it with others facing the same issue. In my case, I resolved this by:

1. Downloading the `MaterialIcons-Regular.tff` font inside `web/assets/fonts` dir.
2. Adding `[{"fonts":[{"asset":"fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf"}],"family":"MaterialIcons"}]` in the file `web/assets/FontManifest.json`

Comment: I am having the same issue with my release version. I added the MaterialIcons-Regular.tff, as for the FontManifest.json, do I create the file and folder for it? and paste the above line in it? or is there a file like that already that I need to download?

Comment: https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/font/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf

Comment: The link doesn't include any icons though.

Answer (score 3):

If your assets/icons working in debug mode and are not showing in release mode, please consider this simple hack:

1. run the web app in debug mode.
2. When running, open the build folder and look for `flutter_assets` folder:

   ```
    build/flutter_assets
   ```
3. copy `fonts` folder and `FontManifest.json` from `flutter_assets`.
4. paste them to your web folder `web/assets` and TADAAA!
5. `flutter clean`> delete build folder > `flutter pub get`> `flutter run --release`